# 500 error after installing su_php, permissions issues, "UID of script "/index.php" is smaller than min_uid"

Tags: amazon-ec2, permissions, suphp

I have just installed `su_php` on my server (amazon ec2 instance), It is required for 1 of my applications.

Now, I am getting a `500 Internal server error` when visiting all of my hosted sites.

The error logs:

```
[error] [client ip] SoftException in Application.cpp:350: UID of script "/var/www/html/www.mywebsite.org.uk/index.php" is smaller than min_uid
[error] [client ip] Premature end of script headers: index.php
```

`ls -l` of the webroot show:

```
drwxrwxr-x  2 root     root 4096 Aug  7 14:23 aws.anothersite.co.uk
drwxrwxr-x  7 ec2-user root 4096 Oct  5 18:36 content.mywebsite.org.uk
drwxrwxr-x  5 root     root 4096 Sep 14 20:19 anothersite.co.uk
drwxrwxr-x  2 root     root 4096 Oct  5 18:51 logs
drwxrwxr-x  7 ec2-user root 4096 Oct  5 18:37 new.mywebsite.org.uk
drwxr-xr-x  9 root     root 4096 Aug  7 14:10 phpmyadmin
drwxrwxr-x  4 root     root 4096 Sep 10 20:39 wttw.anothersite.co.uk
drwxrwxr-x 27 ec2-user root 4096 Oct  5 18:26 www.mywebsite.org.uk
```

The three domains I want under `su_php` control (if possible) are:

```
drwxrwxr-x 27 ec2-user root 4096 Oct  5 18:26 www.mywebsite.org.uk
drwxrwxr-x  7 ec2-user root 4096 Oct  5 18:36 content.mywebsite.org.uk
drwxrwxr-x  7 ec2-user root 4096 Oct  5 18:37 new.mywebsite.org.uk
```

All of these sites are down and throwing a `500 Internal Server Error`.

All `anothersite.co.uk` domains and subdomains, I want under normal `mod_php` control.

`ls -l` of the **inside the directory** `www.mywebsite.org.uk`

```
I removed most files, they all have the same perms as the below

-rw-rw-r--  1 ec2-user root     0 Oct  5 18:26 googleee78b20b75ffd653.html
drwxrwxr-x 23 ec2-user root 20480 Oct  5 18:26 images
drwxrwxr-x  2 ec2-user root  4096 Oct  5 18:26 includes
-r-x--x--x  1 ec2-user root  1956 Oct  5 18:59 index.php
```

My virtual hosts file is below: (as said above, I want only `mywebsite.org.uk` (& subdomains) under `su_php`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/www.mywebsite.org.uk/"
    ServerName www.mywebsite.org.uk
    ServerAlias mywebsite.org.uk
    ErrorLog "/var/www/html/logs/mywebsite.org.uk-error_log"
    CustomLog "/var/www/html/logs/mywebsite.org.uk-access_log" common
    suPHP_Engine on
    suPHP_UserGroup ec2-user ec2-user
    AddHandler x-httpd-php .php .php3 .php4 .php5
    suPHP_AddHandler x-httpd-php
</VirtualHost>
```

**Any help would be much appreciated!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a system to hand to check this on but I seem to recall that the whole tree from the `docroot` down has to be owned by UIDs > min_uid so if you configured

```
docroot=/var/www
```

then directories from (and including /var/`www/...`) need to be configured correctly.